# Curl - always the last Argument is missing, why?

Tags: api, curl, request, deepl

When i use the following Curl command in Terminal on Mac:

```
curl "https://api-free.deepl.com/v2/glossaries" \
    --header "Authorization: DeepL-Auth-Key 0c9649a5-e8f6-632a-9c42-a9eee160c330:fx" \
    --data-urlencode "name=My Glossary" \
    -d "source_lang=en" \
    -d "target_lang=de" \
    --data-urlencode "entries=Hello!    Guten Tag!" \
    -d "entries_format=tsv"
```

I get the following Error:
{"message":"Bad request","detail":"Missing or invalid argument: entries_format"}

But this is an example Request on der Documentation, so it should work.

Answer (score 1):

The tab character in the entries parameter is encoded incorrectly. Modify that line to:

```
    --data-urlencode $'entries=Hello!\tGuten Tag!' \
```

PS: you should reset your authentication key as it is exposed in the code above.